# How to install kpodder

Tags: software-installation

Will someone please give me detailed instructions on how do install kpodder?
I have tried to download and install a tarball, but did not know or understandf how to work it.

Comment: You may have some difficulty building this one as it not seen development over the last decade. Problem will be the qt version I suspect as it does not understand newer libraries....

Answer (score 0):

Install dependencies with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install kdebase-bin kdebase-data kdebase-dev
```

Then start installing kpodder with downloading it:

```
wget http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=36630

tar -jxvf kpodder-0.6.tar.bz2

cd ./kpodder-0.6

./configure

make

sudo make install

sudo ln -s /usr/local/kde/bin/kpodder /usr/bin/kpodder
```

Add it as an application:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/kpodder.desktop
```

Insert into file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=KPodder
Exec=kpodder %u
Icon=/usr/local/kde/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/kpodder.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;AudioVideo;
MimeType=text/rss;text/xml;text/php;application/rss+xml
Comment=A KDE Pocast handler
```

And that is it.

Answer (score 0):

> Go here to download:
>   http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=36630
>
> Dependencies:
>
> $ sudo apt-get install kdebase-bin kdebase-data kdebase-dev
>
> Start installing:
>
> $ wget http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=36630
>
> $ tar -jxvf kpodder-0.6.tar.bz2
>
> $ cd ./kpodder-0.6
>
> $ ./configure
>
> $ make
>
> $ sudo make install
>
> $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/kde/bin/kpodder /usr/bin/kpodder
>
> Add as application:
>
> $ sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/kpodder.desktop
>
> Insert into gedit file:
>
> [Desktop Entry] Encoding=UTF-8 Name=KPodder Exec=kpodder %u
>   Icon=/usr/local/kde/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/kpodder.png
>   Type=Application Categories=Application;AudioVideo;
>   MimeType=text/rss;text/xml;text/php;application/rss+xml Comment=A KDE
>   Pocast handler
>
> Remove files:
>
> $ cd ..
>
> $ sudo rm -Rv kpodder-0.6
>
> Some might have to run the following to get the program icons to show
>   up in the Applications > Sound & Video list:
>
> $ killall gnome-panel

---

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-471897.html